# why my questions get off-topics, please guide me

Tags: discussion

I asked two questions simply about I can't post or upload more than 500 bytes! then it has no relation to php or apache limits. the question is straightforward. then why! why I can't post/upload to the server more than a little bytes.

however later I answered my own questions that it could be the symptoms of packet congestion and I solve it by increasing tcp window and other related tcp parameters

now my question was what was wrong with my questions so that they get off-topics and why no expert here pointed any possibility? are they reluctant or newbies too

- [PHP POST and file upload size limit for 500 bytes](https://serverfault.com/questions/530383/php-post-and-file-upload-size-limit-for-500-bytes)
- [Unable to POST/Upload files to a PHP page](https://serverfault.com/questions/532142/unable-to-post-upload-as-tcp-retransmitssion)

in the first question I even explained that most solutions didn't work in my case

Answer (score 14):

I see two problems with your questions as posted --

First, your questions are not "straightforward" -- though once you know what's causing the problem you're asking about the *answer* certainly is.

Second, you should be *editing your original question to improve it* rather than posting a new question about the exact same topic (this one I'll blame on the folks who closed your first question *without explaining what sort of additional information/testing we'd need to be able to help you*)

> I will merge and edit your questions as an example shortly

---

Now what's important to me is that ***neither of these problems*** merits an off-topic closure -- Perhaps "Unclear what you're asking" with a comment about what additional information we need, but off-topic seems incorrect to me in these cases.

Ultimately you found *a* solution (perhaps not the best one, but I've reopened your second question so it may get some additional suggestions), which is good, but the community needs to provide better guidance in cases like this.

This matter will be taken up at the next board meeting (which is where I gather the regular users in a room and beat them with a board).

Comment: Thank you and I appreciate your effort. yes, my first question was closed in a way that there was not a problem and there is no solution for it. while it was an actual problem I encounter here and I finally could find a solution which may helps many with this situation. in the first one it was an odd problem since I couldn't post more than few bytes (there are many similar problems with large data but no one as little bytes as this) and I explained it well. as it was closed it made me reluctant to write all them again and I asked about retransmission error which I guessed the cause. anyway tx

Comment: Where do I subscribe for the next meeting to be beaten with a board? Is it possible to have the board exchanged by birch twigs and have the meeting scheduled in the nearest [banya](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banya_(sauna)#Bathing_ritual)?

Comment: @syneticon-dj Board options include "Board", "Board-with-Nail", "Clue-by-Four", and "One-by-Clue". We traditionally schedule the meetings in the generator bay during load tests -- it's LIKE a sauna, but loud enough that nobody can hear the screams :-D

Comment: Well here is a example of what apparently never happens.  How many others just give up and leave rather than coming onto meta to ask? No doubt those who disagree will find some technicality to nitpick rather than see the core message.

Comment: Good to see you dealing with it sensibly @voretaq7 but we need to stop it from happening so much in the first place.